# DotNetZip - How to extract to working directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to get a method that uses the DotNetZip library to extract a file to the current working directory, although I can't seem to get it to do it, it wants a file path:

```
private void unzipfiles()
{
    using (var zip = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read("ccsetup307.zip"))
    {
        zip.ExtractAll("directory-name", 
                       ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
}
```

Comment: zip.ExtractAll(".",ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract to the current directory, why don't you use the `GetCurrentDirectory` method and pass that in as the expected parameter like so:

```
using (var zip = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read("ccsetup307.zip"))
{
    zip.ExtractAll(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
                  ,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx

I know it isn't implicit but it should work fine for you.

Comment: Hi thanks, but this doesn't work, I found out how to do it though: zip.ExtractAll(".",ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);  (Use the period character)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code as well.

```
string x = "your file name";
 using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(x))
{
zip.ExtractAll(Path.GetDirectoryName(x), ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```